# How to get "reversed" time windows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

(Note: I am pretty sure that this is not a duplicate question.)

I need "reversed" time windows from a pandas Dataframe. "reversed" as in I need them to have the last time index after processing them. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), 100],
    [pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:01'), 101],
    [pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:03'), 103],
    [pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:04'), 111]
], columns=['time', 'value']).set_index('time')

>>>
                     value
time                      
2018-01-01 00:00:00    100
2018-01-01 00:00:01    101
2018-01-01 00:00:03    103
2018-01-01 00:00:04    111
```

Normally you could just reverse the dataframe and call `.rolling` on that, but *pandas* does not like reversed time indices:

```
df[::-1].rolling('2s')

>>> ValueError: index must be monotonic
```

Now, "reversed" time windows are just "forward" time windows shifted in time:

```
ws = df.rolling('2s').mean()
ws.index = ws.index + pd.Timedelta(2, unit='s')

>>>

                     value
time                      
2018-01-01 00:00:02  100.0
2018-01-01 00:00:03  100.5
2018-01-01 00:00:05  103.0
2018-01-01 00:00:06  107.0
```

But due to the non uniform sampling this leads to time indices that are not aligned with the original data.

I have some code that works by slicing the windows manually, but that is prohibitively slow.

For reference, the result I would expect is:

```
                     value
time                      
2018-01-01 00:00:00  100.5
2018-01-01 00:00:01  101.0
2018-01-01 00:00:03  107.0
2018-01-01 00:00:04  111.0
```

So windows with the current timestamp looking forward in time.

Comment: fyi, your question reminded me of an issue on the pandas github which was open some time. Seems it's still not fixed, added your example there with some more attempts: [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6772)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with a `reindex`... and then another `reindex`.

```
u = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + pd.Timedelta('2s'), freq='1s')

df.reindex(u).ffill().rolling(2).mean().shift(-1).reindex(df.index)
```

```
                     value
time
2018-01-01 00:00:00  100.5
2018-01-01 00:00:01  101.0
2018-01-01 00:00:03  107.0
2018-01-01 00:00:04  111.0
```

Comment: Added your answer to a long time opened [github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6772)

Comment: Ha, I remember seeing that one.  Not hopeful at all it will ever get added though :P

Comment: Uh ... that's ugly ... And it blows up the sparse dataframe to the full 1 Hz frequency before the final reindex. My poor RAM. It's still faster than the alternative ... thanks I guess :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok ... After reading @user3483203 answer I experimented with manipulating the index and came up with this:

```
def reverse_df(df):

    # reverse dataset
    reverse_df = df.iloc[::-1]
    ri = reverse_df.index

    # re-reverse index
    reverse_df.index = ri[0] - ri + ri[-1]

    # done
    return(reverse_df)


reverse_df(reverse_df(df).rolling('2s').mean())

>>>

                     value
time                      
2018-01-01 00:00:00  100.5
2018-01-01 00:00:01  101.0
2018-01-01 00:00:03  107.0
2018-01-01 00:00:04  111.0
```

This is basically reversing the `DataFrame` then reversing the time index, keeping the relative time deltas intact. That gives us a monotonic time index that `.rolling` is able to handle, but requires us to reverse the `DataFrame` again in the end.

I wanted to give timings to compare both versions, but @user3483203's version does not finish on my dataset :-)